# Упростить выражение

Tags: python

Всем привет!

Есть словарь:

```
 p = {'DHCP-Client-IP-Address': '0.0.0.0'}
```

Как получить в одной выражении если значение '0.0.0.0' значит это None, важно также быстродействие.

```
cip = p.get('DHCP-Client-IP-Address', None)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cip = p['DHCP-Client-IP-Address'] if p['DHCP-Client-IP-Address'] != '0.0.0.0' else None
```